# Views at TableRow disable TableRow's onClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, tablerow

I am adding tableRow's dynamically into a tableLayout.

Then, I am adding TextViews into TableRows, then, i have to click on the tableRow's corners to get the  TableRow's onClickListener.
That's because it's actually  getting the TableRow's inside view's onClickListener.(textview's onclickListener)

My code:

```
Cursor resultado = dh.fetchAllFornecedores();//buscando no banco
    resultado.moveToFirst();
    for(int i=0;i<resultado.getCount();i++){

        TableRow tr= (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tablerowfornecedor, null);
        HorizontalScrollView hsc= (HorizontalScrollView)tr.getChildAt(0);
        LinearLayout linearl= (LinearLayout)hsc.getChildAt(0);
        tr.setClickable(true);
        tr.setOnClickListener(this);



       for(int j=0;j<linearl.getChildCount();j++){ //para cada textfild dos Fornecedores
                TextView textv=(TextView)linearl.getChildAt(j);
                textv.setClickable(false);
                textv=(TextView)linearl.getChildAt(j);

                if(j==0)textv.setText(resultado.getString(resultado.getColumnIndex("nome")));               
                else if(j==1)textv.setText(resultado.getString(resultado.getColumnIndex("doc1")));
                else if(j==2)textv.setText(resultado.getString(resultado.getColumnIndex("rua"))+", "+(resultado.getString(resultado.getColumnIndex("numero"))));
                else if(j==3)textv.setText(resultado.getString(resultado.getColumnIndex("id_fornecedor")));
            }
       tl.addView(tr,tlp);
       trs.add(tr);
       resultado.moveToNext();

    }
```

dh is my database class.

How can i "disable" the click on my TableRow's inside views?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` (for a parent activity)

or:

`ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` (for parent layout)

to intercept the motion events before they're dispatched to their childs.

Comment: And what about the MotionEvent , what should i do? Sorry my ignorance... =x